# Hierarchical Columns in Panda

Tags: python, pandas

I have following Pandas DataFrame:
[image]

and would like to convert the columns to look like this:

[image]

How can I create column hierarchy?
Thank you for any pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)
```